I want to write indexes after every log in a file
so basically what the titles say(if possible dumb it down a bit I just began this whole coding thing)
#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Math(double v, double angle);

int main()
{
    double velocity;
    double angle;

    cout << "input velocity(m/s): "<< "\n";
    cin >> velocity;   
    cout << "input angle(deg): "<< "\n";
    cin >> angle;

    Math(velocity, angle);
}

void Math(double v, double angle)
{
    double g = 9.8;
    double Vx = v*cos(angle * M_PI/180);
    double Vy = v*sin(angle * M_PI/180);

    double s;
    double t;
    double h;

    h = (Vy*Vy)/(2*g);
    t = 2*Vy/g;
    s = Vx*t;
    
    cout << "distance traveled: " << s << " meters" << "\n";
    cout << "maximum height reached: "<< h << " meters" << "\n";
    cout << "time of travel: " << t << " seconds" << "\n";

    ofstream logbook("logbook.txt");
    logbook<< "\n";//instead of this line I want the No.
    logbook << "distance traveled: " << s << " meters" << "\n";
    logbook << "maximum height reached: "<< h << " meters" << "\n";
    logbook << "time of travel: " << t << " seconds" << "\n";
}

I used doubles as variables because I need as much flexibility with input as possible.
log 1.
distance traveled: 883.699 meters
maximum height reached: 127.551 meters
time of travel: 10.2041 seconds
 log 2.
.
.
.

this is basically how the log file should look like after the input, I didn't quite understand how to use or should I use the getline() function. I don't think it needs more explaining.
I tried using the getline() but I need to not only read what is on that number line but also to write the next number line depending on what the previous number was.
P.S I just found out that the output itself isn't being saved can anyone help?

Re: "I used doubles as variables because I need as much flexibility with input as possible" - long doubles usually gives even bigger flexibility.

You could just store the log number in a file - or read the number from the logfile.

I'd do it by having a separate logbook_index.txt file that has just the last log index in it, then read in that value, increment it by one, and write back out the updated new last log index to that file.

Are you trying to log multiple runs of Math to the same file? Your use of ofstream will overwrite the file each time, instead of append to it.

'The output itself isn't being saved' That's the default behavour of ofstream, each time you run your program it will create a new file, destroying the contents of any old file. To preserve the old file you need ofstream logbook("logbook.txt", ios_base::app);
